# Error when trying to connect VS2015 with Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have used workaround from [this blog post](http://mscrmdaily.com/2015/05/22/crm-developer-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/) to install MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Developer Toolkit on Visual Studio 2015. Many people have installed it and using it without problems. However, when I try to bind to my online CRM instance, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Host,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: What does the toolkit give you that you are wanting?

Comment: Hi Daryl. I'm just starting out with CRM development. Most of the tutorials online for creating client side scripts and plugins are based on this. I have managed to not to get this error when I select version of .NET > 4.5.2 when creating solution. But I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got .NET Framework 4.5.2 installed? I remember having to install this, even on Windows 10 which is supposed to have it.

Comment: I figured out it works whenever I select .NET > 4.5.2. I don't know why is that, but got it working....

Comment: Because CRM 2015 is written with .NET 4.5.2 :p